# How can I install a very old game on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, compatibility

I'm trying to install Theme Hospital on my Windows 7 machine but I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've tried setting it to run in XP compatability mode but didn't hold out much hope, and as expected I still got this error.

Is there a way I can force this application to run in 32-bit mode or something?

Comment: 16-bit games cannot natively run under 64-bit Windows. You'll have to use some kind of workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you install a [virtual machine of Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)

If it's DOS game, try [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/)

Comment: It's a DOS game and is supported by DosBox: http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=663&letter=T

Answer (score 0):

[Long Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode), which is required to run a 64-bit operating system on a x86-class machine, does not support Virtual 8086 Mode, which is required to play old games. Use an emulator or a virtual machine instead.